# How do I use a JSON file as a database for dummy users in my React Hooks e-commerce app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I am creating a frontend dummy e-commerce app. I have created a login page, and the idea is to link the JSON database of users which all have a unique username, password and ID and when you try to login with the parameters you get the Login successful message if there is a user with those parameters in the JSON, and if there is not you get the Fail message. Below is my source code for the login page. For now I have just made a simple if user = user@gmail.com and password = user password, then you get the success message, but the idea is to use the database for multiple user options. The JSON file will be a basic array of user objects.

P.S. stack overflow wont let me post the code unless I put constant and be grammatically correct so I had to separate the use State use navigate and so on

```
const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const [valid, setValid] = useState(false)
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const handle Submit = (e) => {
      if (email === 'user@gmail.com' && password === 'user password') {
        setValid(true)
        setSuccess(true)
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigate('/')
        },3000)
      }
      e.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. what is your question?

Comment: 2. you can't expose usernames and passwords to the client as json, you must validate it on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will imagine your users array is like so per your description

```
const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John',email: 'user1@gmail.com', password: '123456' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Pete' , email: 'user2@gmail.com', password: '123456' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Mary' , email: 'user3@gmail.com', password: '123456' },
];
```

your submit function will be like so

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = users.find((user) => user.email === email && user.password === password);
    if (user) {
       // login success
    }
    else {
         // login failed
    }
}
```

this will check if the user info exists in your JSON data or not
you can replace the login success comment and failure wth your specific logic

Comment: you welcome @AndrejNedeljkovic ,
glad that I could help,

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package json-server https://github.com/typicode/json-server or maybe another package that does the same thing.